# Clustering issue in JSF+CDI+Wildfly

Tags: cdi, wildfly, jsf-2.2, wildfly-8

I am using wildlfly 8.2.0 and apache2.2(as load balancer) and developing application in JSF 2.2. I marked my web application as distributable and I am injecting enterprise event in my CDI bean.

```
@Inject
Event<KillEvent> killEvent;
```

While switching to other nodes, I am getting below error. How to resolve this error?

```
2016-02-23 15:09:20,148 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-63) UT005023: Exception handling request to /LRP/main.xhtml: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-001122: Failed to deserialize annotated type identified with AnnotatedTypeIdentifier [contextId=LRP.war, bdaId=/F:/TRUST2/apps1/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/content/LRP.war, className=com.svm.lrp.nfr.main.bean.IndexCBean, suffix=null, modified=false]
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.SlimAnnotatedType$SerializationProxy.readResolve(SlimAnnotatedType.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callReadResolve(SerializableClass.java:413)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1286)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1745)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1658)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1606)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1745)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1658)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1745)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1658)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1745)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1658)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1606)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1745)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1658)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1745)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1658)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockUnmarshaller.readObject(BlockUnmarshaller.java:149)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockUnmarshaller.readObject(BlockUnmarshaller.java:135)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectInputStream.java:53)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(RiverObjectInputStream.java:307)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:365)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1396)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callReadObject(SerializableClass.java:307)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1637)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.jboss.SimpleMarshalledValue.get(SimpleMarshalledValue.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.jboss.SimpleMarshalledValue.get(SimpleMarshalledValue.java:44)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.jboss.MarshalledValueMarshaller.read(MarshalledValueMarshaller.java:45)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.jboss.MarshalledValueMarshaller.read(MarshalledValueMarshaller.java:32)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.coarse.CoarseSessionAttributesFactory.findValue(CoarseSessionAttributesFactory.java:84)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.coarse.CoarseSessionAttributesFactory.findValue(CoarseSessionAttributesFactory.java:48)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.InfinispanSessionFactory.findValue(InfinispanSessionFactory.java:63)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.InfinispanSessionFactory.findValue(InfinispanSessionFactory.java:40)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.InfinispanSessionManager.findSession(InfinispanSessionManager.java:234)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.DistributableSessionManager.getSession(DistributableSessionManager.java:140)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.getSession(ServletContextImpl.java:726)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getSession(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:370)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.SessionHolder.requestInitialized(SessionHolder.java:47)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.HttpContextLifecycle.requestInitialized(HttpContextLifecycle.java:231)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener.requestInitialized(WeldInitialListener.java:152)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.requestInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:245)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:283)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in object of type org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.SlimAnnotatedType$SerializationProxy
    in field type
    in object of type org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedField$SerializationProxy
    in field field
    in object of type org.jboss.weld.injection.attributes.InferringFieldInjectionPointAttributes
    in field attributes
    in object of type org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint
    in field injectionPoint
    in object of type org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl$SerializationProxy
    in field killEvent
    in object of type com.svm.lrp.nfr.main.bean.IndexCBean
    in field instance
    in object of type org.jboss.weld.context.SerializableContextualInstanceImpl
    in object of type java.util.HashMap
```

I have deployed same code in wildfly 10 also. But getting same error.

Comment: Well your error indicates Wildfly 10 in the path, but that's fine.  Could you provide the definition of IndexCBean?  In addition to KillEvent?

Comment: I have tried the same thing in wildlfy 10, but got same error. IndexCBean is my cdi bean with sessionscope., where i have injected the event. If i comment out injection the kill event, everything works fine

Comment: how is this jsf related?

Comment: Ah... you're trying to serialize over the cluster the CDI event.  Try making the field transient.

Comment: Am getting same error even if i make it as transient